# Convert mailchimp3 client.lists.members.all to dataframe or csv python

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am attempting to use the mailchimp3 library to connect to my Mailchimp instance via API. I am successfully getting the data out using the below request but am really struggling to do anything with the data once I have it saved in a variable.

```
from mailchimp3 import MailChimp

client = MailChimp(mc_api='my_api')

response = client.lists.members.all('list_id', get_all = True)
```

I have tried various methods but the main issue I seem to be something up against is that the response is multiple lines of JSON data. I think each record is a new JSON line and I am just struggling to work with data in that format. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this was really simple and after days of trying to solve it I am a little embarrassed but in case anyone else gets stuck.

I just used pands json_normalise on the response dictionary, specifically the members key and out came a lovely table:

```
client = MailChimp(mc_api='*****')

response = client.lists.members.all('*****', get_all = True)

df = pd.json_normalize(response['members'])

df.to_csv('mailchimp_member_data.csv')
```